# Javascript: Loop Through every third child node

Tags: javascript, dom

If I got a parent node, how can I loop through every third child node?

I've got now this code:

```
var parents = document.getElementById('ID_of_parent');
var first_child = parents.firstChild.data.id;
alert(parents);
alert(first_child);
```

For the parents, i got now '*[object HTMLDivElement]*' and for first_child i got '*undefined*'.

Comment: what does `alert(parents.firstChild.data)` and `alert(parents.firstChild.data.id)` give you? This is where the problem lies.

Comment: .data gives me "" (empty), and .data.id gives me "undefined"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
var nodes = document.getElementById('ID_of_parent').childNodes;
for(i=0; i<nodes.length; i+=3) {
    alert(nodes[i]);
}
```

Comment: This returns 'document.getElementById("ID_of_parent").childNodes is not a function'?

Comment: @Florian fixed, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you consider jQuery?

```
$("#ID_of_parent > *:nth-child(3n)").each(function() { alert(this);});
```

I implemented a demo here: http://jsbin.com/ahije4/5

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed: only return tags (not text-nodes f.e.). Also using nth-child-selector instead of fiddling with .children(), is pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

The `element.childNodes` collection is what you need.
You need to skip the child nodes that are not elements (`element.nodeType != 1`).

```
var d = document.getElementById("ID_of_parent");
    if (d)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < d.childNodes.length; i++)
        {
            if (d.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1)
                alert(typeof(d.childNodes[i]) + "- " + d.childNodes[i].nodeType + ": " + d.childNodes[i].tagName + " - " + d.childNodes[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I try it but got this in my console: `length` is undefined function

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeSkippingIterator(parent,stride) {
    if(isNaN(stride) || stride < 1)
        stride = 1
    var node = parent.firstChild
    return function() {
        var returnable = node,
            cnt = stride
        while(--cnt >= 0 && node) {
            node = node.nextElementSibling
        }
        return returnable
    }
}
```

keep calling the generator you get back until it has no value for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) and or [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) with jQuery

```
//set node attribute
($('#ID_of_parent > third_child').css( 'propertyName' , 'value' );

//execute each nodes
$.each($('#ID_of_parent'), function( key, child ) {
    console.log(child);
});
```

You may see a working sample here:
https://jsfiddle.net/chetabahana/8x65wq32/20/