# Add Class to every 3rd Element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, selector, nodes

I'm trying to select every third element of a parent with javascript and add a css class to it. Sounds pretty simple to me but I can't get it work.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274673/javascript-loop-through-every-third-child-node?s=773e8b37-d89e-4c60-8512-9279e30cb5dd) thread which looked quite nice to me to get that done, but I'm such a wuss with javascript that my tries didn't work out:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("ParentsClassName").childNodes;
for(i=0; i<nodes.length; i+=3) {
  this.className += ' newClassName';
}​
```

When I load this, nothing happens at all.
Any fixes, eyeopeners and tips appreciated.
Greetings, Marian

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass"),
    forEach = Array.prototype.forEach.call.bind(Array.prototype.forEach),
    filter = Array.prototype.filter.call.bind(Array.prototype.filter)

forEach(parents, addClassToEveryThirdChild)

function addClassToEveryThirdChild(parent) {
    filter(parent.children, selectEveryThirdChild)
        .forEach(addSomeClass)
}

function selectEveryThirdChild(elem, i) {
    return i % 3 === 0
}

function addSomeClass(elem) {
    elem.classList.add("newClassName")
}
```

Or with loops

```
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass")

for (var i = 0, ii = parents.length; i < ii; i++) {
    var parent = parents[i],
        children = parent.children

    for (var j = 0, jj = children.length; j < jj; j++) {
        var elem = children[j]
        if (j % 3 === 0) {
            elem.classList.add("newClassName")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This answer is the correct one. Though I don't see the benefit of both `filter` and `forEach`.

Comment: @amnotiam Reducing the filter and forEach into one statement is a micro optimization. Sure you can use an if in forEach.

Comment: Not worried about optimization. Just cleaner code. Wish I could give another +1 for daring to omit semicolons on StackOverflow.

Comment: @amnotiam Clean code is hard to do. I'm sure if I rewrote the code with for loops it would be a lot more readable :P

Comment: Wish I could give another +1, too. Rare to see clean code in an answer.

Comment: @Raynos: Yeah, personal preference I guess. I wasn't meaning traditional loops. Just that the `.filter` seemed unnecessary since the reduced set is discarded after the work is done. Not a big deal. Your updated solution *(at the top)* is a nice approach.

Comment: @amnotiam the only reason to use filter instead of an `if` is to reduce the level of nesting by 1. Also for maintainability, so you can swap in a more complex filtering function if needed.

Comment: Yes, my comments about `filter` were only with respect to your original solution. Using named functions so that you can drop something else in easily makes it much more compelling.

Comment: Zero complaints about "why you no semicolon" or "why you ES5 / DOM3". Where did all the old guys go :P

Comment: I just can't believe there's not one comment or answer promising that all things are better with jQuery.

Comment: Sorry for the late approval. This works like a charm. I had some issues at first because I added whitespace before the new class name, suggesting the function wouldn't do it itself. I really admire Stackoverflow for its wonderful community. You guys are great. I additionally read up on semicolons and JS validators after your discussion – eyeopener :) Thank you very much Raynos

Answer (score 7):

I found that the most straight-forward approach to determining every *third*, is to add 1 to index when doing the modulus:

```
var nodes = //get nodes

for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  var isThirdIteration = (i + 1) % 3 === 0;

  if (isThirdIteration) {
    this.className += ' newClassName';
  }
}​
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with pure CSS. Javascript isn't needed ;)

Example: `.parent .child:nth-of-type(3n+3)`

Answer (score 0):

This returns a list of elements:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ParentsClassName")
```

You can either iterate over the list, or select an index:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ParentsClassName")[0].childNodes;
```