# Keep alternate background color logic when removing elements

Tags: javascript, php, css

To start with, my site is built with WP as CMS, and ofc written in php. I have a page that is built up by sections. The sections are custom post types and are appearing only if they have posts in them. The sections are set as functions and have different row and background color settings. The colors should be light grey and white every other section so that the UI looks nice.

My challenge is that if the customer deletes all posts in one of the cpt's, then the section disappears "as it should" but then it creates two sections after one another with the same color. Not very nice to look at. I have fuzzed around a bit with javascript just on this project so I am a complete beginner at it. Any suggestions to what I might do here or am I totally on the wrong path from the beginning?

Here is how the sections are built on the page template:

```
<?php lol_section_bg_open(); ?> 
<h2 id="countMe" class="type2" style="margin-bottom:0"><?php _e(' announcements', 'theme'); ?></h2>

<?php lol_innerSection_open(); ?>
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'adhoc',
    'posts_per_page' => 3
);
$Query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $Query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $Query->have_posts() ) : $Query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="global-margin-bottom">
        <?php get_template_part( 'parts/content', 'date' ); ?>:
        <br/>
        <span class="bold">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </span>
        <br/>                   
        <?php get_template_part( 'parts/content', 'readmoreButton' ); ?>                                
    </div>   
<?php endwhile; ?>      
<?php else : ?>
    <p><em><?php _e('Currently there are no announcements.', 'theme'); ?></em></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php lol_innerSection_close(); ?>
<?php lol_section_close(); ?>
<?php
```

Here is my function that i get to set the section rows and bg:

```
function lol_section_open() {
echo '<div class="row section">';
echo '<div class="small-12 columns">';
echo '<div class="row">';
echo '<div class="small-12 large-8 large-centered columns">';
echo '<div class="row">';
echo '<div class="small-12 xxlarge-8 columns">';}
```

The function with bg color:

```
function lol_section_bg_open() {
echo '<div class="row section empLight">';
echo '<div class="small-12 columns">';
echo '<div class="row">';
echo '<div class="small-12 large-8 large-centered columns">';
echo '<div class="row">';
echo '<div class="small-12 xxlarge-8 columns">';}
```

And i will probably regret this, but here is as far as i have gotten on my js:

```
var x = {};

function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("section").length;
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = x;

} 

if (x % 2 == 0)
{
//my code
}
else
{
//my code
}
```

Comment: take a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385140/add-class-to-every-3rd-element-with-javascript

Comment: another way would be to use CSS, something like: `your-element:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
your-element:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}`

Comment: Yes, it is better to use CSS solution with nth-child(even) and nth-child(odd) for theme(color scheme) without adding any color specific class.

Comment: Wonderful:) Used nth-child odd/even now. Worked like a charm, thank you! @RST

Comment: And @Tahir Shahzad